# How to retrieve captured Image when changing orientation in Android?

Tags: android

I have a code for capturing image in Activity using Camera and displaying it in Image View. It works fine in most of devices, but when it comes to Samsung, as soon as I rotate device the image vanishes. What should I do to retrieve state of captured image during orientation or lock orientation at all

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //Bitmap photo = ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: add android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" in menifest Activity tag

Comment: @DivyeshPatel - No that doesn't work, because samsung captures image in landscape and while it shows in Activity, the orientation changes automatically into portrait and I lose data

Comment: then override onconfigurationChange and save image state

Comment: Try impementing onConfigurationChange

Comment: Any Example related to above code I shared?

Answer (score 0):

You can checks the orientation of the screen

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

    }
}
```

Comment: Finding difficulty in mapping your code with mine, if you can integrate yours with mine and post would be helpful